# Angular feature modules dragdropmodule unknown property

Tags: angular, angular-module, angular-cdk-drag-drop

I'm trying to modularize an application. I followed these instructions: https://angular.io/guide/feature-modules

When trying to import the draganddrop module in a component under the feature module, i'm getting the following error:

```
Can't bind to 'cdkDropListData' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
    class="container"
    cdkDropList
    [ERROR ->][cdkDropListData]="data"
    (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event, i)"
  >
```

What I did:
1. Added FeatureModule in app.module.ts imports
2. Added DragDropModule in import and export in feature.module.ts

Can anyone advise me on what I'm doing wrong please?

```
@NgModule({
 imports: [CommonModule, FontAwesomeModule, DragDropModule],
 declarations: [DashboardComponent],
 exports: [DragDropModule]
 })
 export class FeatureModule {}
```

package.json

`{
  "name": "angular-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~9.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "~9.1.9",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^4.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.27",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.12.1",
    "@ngrx/store": "^9.2.0",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.901.7",
    "@angular/cli": "~9.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~9.1.9",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}`

Comment: By "under the feature module", you mean that your component is declared in the feature module?

Comment: yes, I have the dashboard component declared in the feature module. I just updated my question and added the code in the feature module

Comment: That's weird.... could you post your `package.json`?

Comment: I added the package.json.
In the app.module.ts, I added the feature module in imports

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your package.json... if it's not a brand new project, try to remove `node_modules`, `package-lock.json` and `npm install` it again.

Comment: ok, i'll try this and update you. thank you

Just a quick question, for example when using a module such as dragDropModule in a feature module, we just need to import the dragdrop module in the feature module to be able to use it in the feature module components?

Comment: Yes. In some cases, the module demands configurations, but usually, you just have to import the module in the module you're planning to use its features. That's the case do `CdkDragDropModule`.